# What kind of bug is this? I found it on my Cleome plant in Atlanta Georgia

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image][image][image][image]
This bug was on my cleome plant in Atlanta Georgia

Comment: It is an immature from the order Hemiptera. I am sure of that, but cannot help further.

Comment: @KarlKjer If you want to take the time, I think it might be worth posting a canonical immature hemiptera post with some identifying characteristics and any particularly interesting individual examples (you seem to be the most active arthropod ID answerer lately), then we can close and direct people there; although this is the only one I recall recently, I feel like since I've been here there have been a lot of questions on them, especially with the spread of certain shield bugs.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [instar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instar) (nymph) of a shield or stink  bug (order [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera), family [Pentatomidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae)).

Specifically, it appears quite similar to a later juvenile stage (~4th instar) of *Chinavia hilaris*, the [**Green Stink Bug**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_stink_bug).

[image]

<sup>4th instar; Source: [Oregon Dept of Agriculture](https://www.odaguides.us/chinavia-hilaris.html)</sup>

[image]

<sup>4th instar; Source: [UF IFAS](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/CREATURES/VEG/BEAN/green_stink_bug.htm); Credit: Herb Pilcher, USDA-ARS, Bugwood.org.</sup>

[Alain Hogue](https://bugguide.net/user/view/102902) also captured a wonderful picture of this species at [bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/1637020/bgimage)

From [UF IFAS](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/CREATURES/VEG/BEAN/green_stink_bug.htm):

> **Distribution**
> The green stink bug occurs in most of eastern North America, from Quebec and New England west through southern Canada and the northern U.S. to the Pacific Coast, and southwest from Florida though California. This is the most commonly encountered stink bug species in North America.